# xsl-fo: pdf looks fine on the screen, but when printed to xerox machine, i see blocks

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo

I'm able to format my pdf fine with the following code, and looks fine on the screen and prints well to my dell laser printer, however, the spaces below will turn into blocks when I print to the xerox workcentre pro printer.  See code:

```
<fo:block-container >
    <fo:block font-size="15pt" margin-top=".10in" font-family="Univers Medium" >Fax:&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<xsl:value-of select="deliveryInfo/faxNumber"/></fo:block>
    <xsl:variable name="dateTime" select="creationDate"/>
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($dateTime, ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before($date, '-')" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '-'), '-')" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '-'), '-')" />
    <fo:block font-size="15pt" margin-top=".10in" font-family="Univers Medium" >Date:&#160;&#160;&#160;<xsl:value-of select="concat($day, '-', $month, '-', $year)" /></fo:block>
    <fo:block font-size="15pt" margin-top=".10in" font-family="Univers Medium" >Pages:</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

note the use of

```
&#160;
```

Comment: Sounds like the Xerox replaces the Univers font with something else. Change the printer preferences to prevent this.

Comment: Did you embed the fonts in the PDF file? Every FO processor should have a way to do it.

Comment: well, how come Univers Medium prints fine for characters such as "this is a test" but when I use the ampersand pound 160 semicolon, that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a problem for that particular printer. (But good for you for trying another one!)

Comment: I don't think I'm going to change server printer drivers as that may have an impact on other apps.  It'll have to be a change in code

Answer (score 0):

If your printer is having some issue with  , you could change the structure to use fo:leader and set the leader-length appropriately. This could solve your problem without changing the driver.

```
 <fo:leader leader-length="72pt"/>
```